# EditText lose focus when the soft keyboard is displayed in Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-7.0-nougat

In Android Nougat, the `EditText` loses focus when the keyboard is displayed. This is working fine with all the lower versions.

I am using `requestFocus()` manually to get the focus to the `EditText` and programmatically showing the keyboard. The `EditText` is placed inside a `ListView`.

Could someone help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace ListView with RecyclierView easily, that would be my suggestion. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Add `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` to your `ListView`.
2. Add `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your `EditText`.
3. Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your `Activity` in AndroidManifest file.